# Multivariate Polynomial Regression in R (Prediction)

Tags: r, regression, predict, polynomials

I'm building a prediction model using a 60/40 test split.
I would like to build a polynomial regression model with 10 explanatory variables.

First, I build a model based on training, and I regress on `training$y`.

```
model_poly = lm(training$y ~ poly(training$x1, degree=2, raw=TRUE) +
     poly(training$x2, degree=2, raw=TRUE) +
     poly(training$x3, degree=2, raw=TRUE) +
     poly(training$x4, degree=2, raw=TRUE) +
     poly(training$x5, degree=2, raw=TRUE) +
     poly(training$x6, degree=2, raw=TRUE) +
     poly(training$x7, degree=2, raw=TRUE) +
     poly(training$x8, degree=2, raw=TRUE) +
     poly(training$x9, degree=2, raw=TRUE) +
     poly(training$x10, degree=2, raw=TRUE))
```

Afterwards, I would like to predict on the new data (`test`) using this model.

```
poly_predictions = predict(model_poly, poly(test$x1, degree=2, raw=TRUE)+
     poly(test$x2, degree=2, raw=TRUE) +
     poly(test$x3, degree=2, raw=TRUE) +
     poly(test$x4, degree=2, raw=TRUE) +
     poly(test$x5, degree=2, raw=TRUE) +
     poly(test$x6, degree=2, raw=TRUE) +
     poly(test$x7, degree=2, raw=TRUE) +
     poly(test$x8, degree=2, raw=TRUE) +
     poly(test$x9, degree=2, raw=TRUE) +
     poly(test$x10, degree=2, raw=TRUE))
```

The test data has around 200k rows and the training data has around 300k rows.

The problem is, `poly_predictions` has the dimension of the training data, and not of the test data. Therefore, something is wrong.

What am I missing here? When predicting with a simple linear model, such as

```
model_lm = lm(training$y ~ ., training)
lm_predictions = predict(model_lm, test)
```

I had no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overspecifying the question.  Since your model formula uses `training$x1`, that's the exact variable it will be looking for when it does the prediction.  Instead, use the fact that the columns share names, and create the model as

```
model_poly = lm(y ~ poly(x1, degree=2, raw=T) +
  poly(x2, degree=2, raw=T), data=df.training)
```

This will product a model in terms of the abstract variables `x1`, `x2`, etc.

Then you can use predict like this (you can omit the `poly` calls here because that's baked into the model):

```
predict(model_poly, df.test)
```

to produce the desired result. Otherwise, you typically get a warning indicating that your output data does not match the `newdata` supplied to predict if they are of different lengths.